# Smooth shading only works when object is selected

Tags: linux

I have issue with smooth shading. When I put smooth shading on some example UV spheres the smoothed sphere is the one which is selected. When I select other sphere, the other is now smoothed. I'm working on Linux and Blender v2.76. My friend told me that it isn't normal behavior. When I did that on Blender on Windows it works normally. How to change that? Pic:
[image]

Comment: This is definitely not normal. Download the latest version of blender directly from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/) and try that one. Also make sure that the drivers for your graphics card are installed correctly.

Comment: @cegaton , I use open source ATi drivers with OpenGL Core 3.3 and Radeon HD5750. The drivers are installed by OS.

Comment: @cegaton The same on newest Blender v2.77a. :(

Comment: AMD  : ( , Have you tried using the proprietary ATI drivers?  http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Comment: @cegaton Proprietary drivers works only on Kernel up to 3.19, on newest Ubuntu I have Kernel 4.6 so I must use Open Source drivers. I suppose it's Blender issue, driver only draws data that Blender send. On gpu benchmark `Unigine Benchmark` all graphics stuff works OK.

Comment: I fount this bug on https://developer.blender.org/T41246

Comment: Buggy drivers... you are out of luck... can you downgrade your kernel to 3.19?

Comment: Probably not, some core applications may be not working (I don't know) on older kernel. I will go with 3D modeling to Windows. Still I think that it is Blender issue, when I change view type on the down from `Solid` to `Material` or `Rendered` or make scene render everything is OK.